# Tensorflow: Trainable Variable Masking

Tags: tensorflow, mask, convolution

I am working on a convolutional neural net that requires some parts of the a kernel weights to be untrainable. tf.nn.conv2d(x, W) takes in a trainable variable W as weights. How can I make some of the elements of W to be untrainable?

Comment: Do you mean you want individual elements of a weight matrix to be un-trainable? Or you want some of your nodes to be un-trainable? I presume this isn't a problem that drop-out would solve?

Comment: I mean I want individual elements of a weight matrix to be un-trainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could have your trainable weights `W1`, a mask `M` indicating where the trainable variables are, and a constant / untrainable weight matrix `W2`, and use

```
W = tf.multiply(W1, tf.cast(M, dtype=W1.dtype)) + tf.multiply(W2, tf.cast(tf.logical_not(M), dtype=W2.dtype))
```